# What are some good ways to Roast Peppers

Tags: vegetables, roasting

I'm looking for a safe method to remove the skin.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a gas range, just fire up a burner. Make sure to have some tongs ready if you can't rest the pepper at a good height above the flame. (You'll probably want them to turn the pepper anyways.)

Once sufficiently blackened (and not on fire mind you) toss in a paper bag and close it. Let it rest and the residual heat inside the pepper will continue to steam it from the inside out.

Once cooled, remove the skin.

Feel free to use water to cool or help remove the skin, but you may wash away some flavorful oils.

I prefer this method as it lets me keep an eye on the pepper the whole time instead of having to peek at a hidden broiler. Plus, you can make sure you get an even roast.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the procedure I use:

1. broil or grill peppers until blackened and blistered all around.
2. immediately pop into pot just large enough to hold.
3. **cover pot tightly**
4. sing two versus of some sea shanty (just joking, really, wait 5 minutes)
5. remove peppers and discover that you can easily scrape off the blackened, burned, skin.

Answer (score 1):

I roast them in the oven till the skin gets dark (blackens, actually).  Then I put them in a paper bag to cool.  The skins slide off easily.  I'm not sure if plastic bags would work but the paper ones do a good job.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I haven't tried plastic, but my guess is it won't cool nearly as fast on its own as it won't allow for the hot moist air to escape. Same could probably be said for foil if tightly wrapped.

Ideally you'd be able to skip the rinse to prevent washing away some of the flavors released during roasting. Sometimes I just can't wait, though, if I mistimed bigger things.

Comment: Agree with not rinsing away the flavors.  I never rinse mine. Small bits of the skin add to the overall taste and appearance (maybe that's just me).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a gas range, roast them on the stovetop. Simply place the pepper directly in the flame, and turn it as it blackens. Once the pepper is completely charred wrap it in aluminum foil. Let it cool for about 15 minutes, then scrape the charred skins off and enjoy.